# Remove specific log line in Android

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I've developed and tested multiple application on many different devices, and one of the most common most annoying thing about reading the logs of the debugged application is the junk log the OS is printing, for example:

GL error log prints on some devices,

```
IMGSRV(2600): :0: GetPTLAFormat: Invalid format
```

Or the other billion logs the current S4 I'm using spits out into the log in all the rainbow colors, which has nothing to do with my application.

I would like instead of filtering in my application TAGs, I would like to filter out device tags, and regexps.

Can this be done?

Comment: There's an option for a custom TAG based filter in the LogCat. There's a button that looks like a green + in the upper right of the log cat window, if you mouse over it says "Create Filter" in the popup from that you can filter by log tag.

Comment: And, in particular, the regexp you use for filtering can use `^` to negate the regexp, thereby serving as a filter. Ed Burnette had posted a recipe for this some time ago, but I don't have a link handy at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a few filtering... they didn't work... I've followed up on @CommonsWare comment, and searched for Ed, found his post, and the bottom line is:

Not:

```
^AbsListView, ^AbsListView|, ^(AbsListView|), or ^(?:...)
```

it is all in the exclamation mark:

```
^(?!AbsListView)
```

You can extend this to:

```
^(?!LogMessageA|LogMessageB)
```

and all the log lines containing these log messages would not show up...

Fantastic!